# Need help on Kendo UI

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, multi-select

I am facing a weird issue while trying to display prepopulated values in a multi-select dropdown menu. `countryData` has a list of countries like IN, US, EU, NZ. Per requirement I need to show IN, EU as presented on UI.

Below is the Select component used in an HTML file.

```html
<select
    class=“countryName"
    kendo-multi-select
    k-option-autobind="false"
    k-data-text-field=“’countryCode'"
    k-data-value-field="'countryCode'"
    k-data-source="vm.countryData"
    ng-model="vm.country”
    k-filter="'contains'">
</select>
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Can you list out fields of datasource ?